# How to create and add multiple new variables into a dataset where the new variables are ased on the same condition

Tags: r, if-statement, variables, dplyr

Suppose I have the following dataframe. What I want to do is to create new variables with prefixes `~new.`, e.g. `new.factor1, new.factor2,` etc. Also, these new variables are created from the old variables based on the same conditions. Let's say the common conditions are that new.factor variables will replace 4 and 5 with 44 and 55 leaving the rest same as before. I want to implement this in a way that I don't have to feed the new names into code for each variable. This is the part I'm stuck with. The solutions I found need to be given the variable names, which I want the solution code to read from the existing variable names.

```
factor1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8,8,9, 9, 10, 10)
factor2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,16,17, 18, 19, 20)
factor3 <- rnorm(20)
factor4 <- c(1:20)
dataset <- data.frame(factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4)
```

Comment: Hi there, your question is a bit unclear. Are you talking about replacing 4 with 44 and 5 with 55 as variable values, or is this something you want to do to the variable names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can help:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
factor1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8,8,9, 9, 10, 10)
factor2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,16,17, 18, 19, 20)
factor3 <- rnorm(20)
factor4 <- c(1:20)
dataset <- data.frame(factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4)
#Mutate
dataset %>%
  mutate(across(c(factor1:factor4),.fns = list(new = ~ ifelse(.==4, 44, ifelse(.==5,55, .))) ))
```

Output:

```
   factor1 factor2     factor3 factor4 factor1_new factor2_new factor3_new factor4_new
1        1       1  0.95562987       1           1           1  0.95562987           1
2        1       2 -1.69133138       2           1           2 -1.69133138           2
3        2       3  0.34527095       3           2           3  0.34527095           3
4        2       4 -0.38068329       4           2          44 -0.38068329          44
5        3       5 -0.88357788       5           3          55 -0.88357788          55
6        3       6  1.09936795       6           3           6  1.09936795           6
7        4       7 -1.44000399       7          44           7 -1.44000399           7
8        4       8 -1.44619802       8          44           8 -1.44619802           8
9        5       9 -0.37914030       9          55           9 -0.37914030           9
10       5      10 -0.38136916      10          55          10 -0.38136916          10
11       6      11  0.05036574      11           6          11  0.05036574          11
12       6      12 -0.61043789      12           6          12 -0.61043789          12
13       7      13 -0.21648782      13           7          13 -0.21648782          13
14       7      14 -0.35230171      14           7          14 -0.35230171          14
15       8      15  0.23007485      15           8          15  0.23007485          15
16       8      16  0.17146377      16           8          16  0.17146377          16
17       9      17  0.77488658      17           9          17  0.77488658          17
18       9      18  0.67676859      18           9          18  0.67676859          18
19      10      19  1.22292180      19          10          19  1.22292180          19
20      10      20  1.07251831      20          10          20  1.07251831          20
```

Based on your question you are trying to create new variables replacing some values. The previous code can address that.